# Drupal 7 Views - How to make exposed filter a drop down of unique data values

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I am using the data module to allow searching and filtering of table data. I am using views to display the data in a table with 3 exposed filters.

I want the user to select from specific values in 2 of the 3 filters. But I am currently only able to display a text box that allows the user to type a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to check out [hook_views_pre_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7). Use it at first in conjunction with dpm() from the devel module to explore the view structure. Then you can directly alter the view (and its filters) before sending it on to be rendered. I would recommend using a php function, like array_unique(), or your own custom function, to loop through and uniquefy your results.

```
mymodule_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  // make sure devel module is turned on first, then take this out when you're
  // done exploring the view results
  dpm($view);
  // this part is pseudocode, I haven't memorized the view structure, but dpm() will
  // show you what to actually put here
  if( $view->name == "my_target_view_machine_name" ) {
    // do your uniquefying here
  }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping that Drupal would have given me something out of the box or there would have been another module I could have used. I wanted to avoid writing code. However I think in the absence of those options your answer is as close as I am going to get. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When adding an exposed filter to a view, drupal gives you two options(Filter type expose): Single filter and Grouped filter, if you choose the Grouped filters, it will let you choose what type of widget do you want.(Radios/Select)

Comment: I have found that the grouped option is not quite what it seems. The term grouped made me think that it would group the data in that that field and show just the unique values that could be selected for filtering, but this is not the case. What it does give you is the option to provide your own values which appear in a drop down but if the data changes then you would have keep going into views and manually adding the new values you want users to be able to select from.

Comment: How did I miss that?  This is just what I needed to use with the Numeric Range field module to easily provide the option to select an 'accommodation sleeps' range from a dropdown.